# Strategy for sharing markup between XAML pages

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 application where I need to share pivot items between multiple pages, e.g.

- page1: sectionA, sectionB, sectionC
- page2: sectionA, sectionB
- page3: sectionC
- […]

Are there any best practices for avoiding duplicated code/markup in such cases?

Comment: I think making a UserControl for each section is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a user control is a great way to share code between pages. Another way is creating a .xaml file with just xaml in it.(no .cs file and no header information)

Comment: Thank you, UserControl definitely seems like a good way. Can you go into details about your second suggestion though?

Comment: Update: The `UserControl` proved to be a very good choice. Exactly what I was looking for.